# HQL nullable property should not be ignored, help?

Tags: join, hql, nullable

I have:

```
Class Foo
{
String name;
String value;
Foo parent; //Foo.parent is OneToOne and nullable
}
```

I have the following HQL:

```
FROM Foo f WHERE 
(lower(f.name) like concat( lower('string') , '%' )) or
(lower(f.value) like concat( lower('string') , '%' )) or
(lower(f.parent.name) like concat( lower('string') , '%' ))
```

The query works great until f.parent is null. Even if the f.name or f.value matches, when f.parent is null, the result is thrown out.

So say I have:

```
Foo a = new Foo();
a.name = "bob";
a.value = "chris";
a.parent = null;

Foo b = new Foo();
b.name = "Bob";
b.value="Chris";
b.parent = a;
```

When I search for "b" only b is returned. I would like it so a and b are returned.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing `f.parent.name` in your query creates an implicit `inner join` on the parent property. To include rows which can not be joined because they have no parent, you'll have to explicitly use a `left outer join` instead:

```
from Foo f
left outer join f.parent as p
where
(lower(f.name) like concat( lower('string') , '%' )) or
(lower(f.value) like concat( lower('string') , '%' )) or
(lower(p.name) like concat( lower('string') , '%' ))
```

[Related HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin. I'm using Oracle and getting the following error: 

ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Is there a way around this? 
Thanks for the help!